# Compile successfully but error occurs at run

Tags: java, super, jcreator

Im a begginer in java and was confuced when I try to run my program...
After I compile it shows that the compile was successful
But as soon as I try to run it, it shows me this message.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: employee.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;D)V
    at academic.<init>(academic.java:19)
    at testEmployee.main(testEmployee.java:16)

Process completed.
```

I created a super class and 2 subclasses. I still unsure about my codes and was unable to find the problem by myself.
this is my codes.

employee.java

```
 public class employee {
    protected String id;
    protected String name;
    protected String ic;
    protected String tel;
    protected double salary;
    protected boolean showEmployee;
    protected static int count;

    public employee(){
        id ="A00000";
        name = "Michele Wong";
        ic = "920412-14-5443";
        tel = "014-6667733";
        salary = 999.00;
    }

    public employee(String id, String name, String ic, String tel, double salary, boolean showEmployee) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.ic = ic;
        this.tel = tel;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.showEmployee = showEmployee;
        count++;
    }
      public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
      }

      public String getId(){
        return id;
      }

      public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
      }

      public String getName(){
        return name;
      }

      public void setIc(String ic){
        this.ic = ic;
      }

      public String getIc(){
        return ic;
      }

      public void setTel(String tel){
        this.tel = tel;
      }

      public String getTel(){
        return tel;
      }

      public void setSalary(double salary){
        this.salary = salary;
      }

      public double getSalary(){
        return salary;
      }

      public void setShowEmployee(boolean showEmployee){
        this.showEmployee = showEmployee;
      }

      public boolean getShowEmployee(){
        return this.showEmployee;
      }

      public String toString(){
        return getId()+ "\t\t\t" +getName()+ "\t\t" +getIc()+ "\t\t" +getTel()+"\t\t";
      }
}
```

admin.java

```
    public class admin extends employee{
    private String position;
    private String department;

    public admin() {
        super();
    }

    public admin(String id, String name, String ic, String tel, double salary, String position, String department) {
        super(id, name, ic, tel, salary);
        this.position = position;
        this.department = department;

    }

    public void setPosition(String position){
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getPosition(){
        return position;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department){
        this.department = department;
    }

    public String getDepartment(){
        return department;
    }

    public double calculateSalary(){
        return super.getSalary() + 100;
    }

    public void DeleteAdmin(){

    }

    public String toString(){
        return super.toString()+ "\t" +getPosition()+ "\t\t\t" +getDepartment()+ "\t\t\t" +calculateSalary();
    }


}
```

academic.java

```
    public class academic extends employee{
    private String subject;
    private String school;

    public academic(){
        super();
    }

    public academic(String id, String name, String ic, String tel, double salary, String subject, String school){
        super(id, name, ic, tel, salary);
        this.subject = subject;
        this.school = school;

    }

    public void setSubject(String subject){
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getSubject(){
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSchool(String school){
        this.school = school;
    }

    public String getSchool(){
        return school;
    }

    public double calculateSalary(){
        return super.getSalary() + 50;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return super.toString()+ "\t" +getSubject()+ "\t\t" +getSchool()+"\t\t\t" +calculateSalary() ;
    }


}
```

testEmployee.java

```
        import java.util.*;
    public class testEmployee {
        private static int totalEmployee = 8;
        private static int employeeID = 1000;

        public static void main(String[]args){

            academic[] aca = new academic[4];
            aca[0] = new academic("A10001", "Jennifer Lee", "930307-14-5556", "012-3456712", 990.00, "Programming", "SAS");
            aca[1] = new academic("A10002", "Harry Tan", "950402-12-2233", "012-1234598", 980.00, "Accounting", "SSH");
            aca[2] = new academic("A10003", "Kelvin Woo", "981225-13-1456", "016-5803157", 990.00, "English for Science", "SBS");
            aca[3] = new academic("A10004", "Terry Yap", "911030-14-5678", "014-9126534", 990.00, "Java", "SAS");

            admin[] admin = new admin[4];
            admin[0] = new admin("A10005", "David Foo", "910922-14-9008", "014-1489763", 1000.00, "Head of Division", "SAS");
            admin[1] = new admin("A10006", "Danny Choo", "930302-15-4443", "012-0987634", 990.00, "Head of Division", "SAD");
            admin[2] = new admin("A10007", "Kelly Tan", "900828-13-3213", "016-8903245", 1100.00,"Head of Division","SOT");
            admin[3] = new admin("A10008", "Donald Heng", "900730-12-6789", "016-9823081", 990.00,"Head of Division","SSH");
            MainMenu(aca, admin);
        }

        //Main Menu
        public static void MainMenu(employee[] aca,employee[] admin){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("********************\n");
            System.out.println("*   MAIN MENU   *\n");
            System.out.println("********************\n");
            System.out.println("1. Display Records \n");
            System.out.println("2. Search Employee\n");
            System.out.println("3. Add Employee\n");
            System.out.println("4. Edit Employee\n");
            System.out.println("5. Delete Employee\n");
            System.out.println("6. Exit \n");
            System.out.print("Please enter your selection: ");
            int selection = input.nextInt();

            switch(selection){
            case 1: Display(aca, admin);
            break;

            case 2: Search(aca, admin);
            break;

            case 3: Add(aca, admin);
            break;

            case 4: Edit(aca, admin);
            break;

            case 5: Delete(aca, admin);
            break;

            case 6:
            System.out.println("Exiting Menu. \nThank you for using the system.");
            System.exit(3);
            break;

            default:
            System.out.println(" Wrong input!\n");
            System.out.println(" Please re-enter \n");
            System.out.println("Press Any Key To Continue...");
            input.nextLine();
            input.nextLine();
            MainMenu(aca, admin);
            break;
          }
        }

        //Display Menu
        public static void Display(employee[] aca,employee[] admin){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("********************\n");
            System.out.println("*   DISPLAY MENU   *\n");
            System.out.println("********************\n");
            System.out.println("1. ACADEMIC \n");
            System.out.println("2. ADMINISTRATIVE \n");
            System.out.println("3. EXIT \n");
            System.out.print("Please enter your selection: ");
            int selection = input.nextInt();

            switch(selection){
            case 1: AcaDisplay(aca, admin);
            break;

            case 2: AdminDisplay(aca, admin);
            break;

            default:
            System.out.println(" Wrong input!\n");
            System.out.println(" Please re-enter \n");
            System.out.println("Press Any Key To Continue...");
            input.nextLine();
            input.nextLine();
            MainMenu(aca, admin);
            break;
            }
        }

        //Display Academic Employee Details
        public static void AcaDisplay(employee[] aca,employee[] admin){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Employee ID \t Employee Name \t\t Employee IC \t Employee Phone Number \t Subject \t\t School \t Salary ");
            for(int i=0; i <totalEmployee; i++){
                System.out.println(aca[i].toString());
            }

            System.out.print("Continue?(Y/N) ");
            char choice = input.next().charAt(0);

            if(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'){
                 MainMenu(aca, admin);
              }
              else if(choice == 'n' || choice == 'N'){
                System.out.println("Exiting Menu. \nThank you for using the system.");
                System.exit(3);
              }
              else {
                System.out.print("\nWrong input. \n Please re-type.");
                AcaDisplay(aca,admin);
              }
        }

        //Display Admin Employee Details
        public static void AdminDisplay(employee[] aca,employee[] admin){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Employee ID \t Employee Name \t Employee IC \t Employee Phone Number \tEmployee Position \t\t Department \tSalary ");
            for(int i=0; i <totalEmployee; i++){
                System.out.println(admin[i].toString());
            }
            System.out.print("Continue?(Y/N) ");
            char choice = input.next().charAt(0);

            if(choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y'){
                 MainMenu(aca, admin);
              }
              else if(choice == 'n' || choice == 'N'){
                System.out.println("Exiting Menu. \nThank you for using the system.");
                System.exit(3);
              }
              else {
                System.out.print("\nWrong input. \n Please re-type.");
                AdminDisplay(aca,admin);
              }
        }

        //Search Employee
        public static void Search(employee[] aca,employee[] admin){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter Employee ID: ");
            String search = input.nextLine();
            for(int i=0; i<totalEmployee; i++){
                if(aca[i].getId() == search){
                    System.out.println("Employee ID \t Employee Name \t\t Employee IC \t Employee Phone Number \t Subject \t\t School \t Salary ");
                    System.out.println(aca[i].toString());
                    }

                else if(admin[i].getId() == search){
                    System.out.println("Employee ID \t Employee Name \t Employee IC \t Employee Phone Number \tEmployee Position \t\t Department \tSalary ");
                    System.out.println(admin[i].toString());
                    }
                else {
                    System.out.print("\nWrong input. \n Please re-type.");
                    Search(aca,admin);
                     }

                }

        }

        //Add Employee
        public static void Add(employee[] aca,employee[] admin){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("********************\n");
            System.out.println("*   DISPLAY MENU   *\n");
            System.out.println("********************\n");
            System.out.println("1. ACADEMIC \n");
            System.out.println("2. ADMINISTRATIVE \n");
            System.out.println("3. EXIT \n");
            System.out.print("Please enter your selection: ");
            int selection = input.nextInt();

            if(selection == 1)
                System.out.println("Academic");
            else
                System.out.println("Administrative");

            Scanner add = new Scanner(System.in);
            char choice;

            do{
                System.out.print("\nEnter New Employee ID :");
                String newID = add.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter New Employee Name :");
                String newName = add.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter New Employee IC :");
                String newIC = add.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter New Employee Phone Number :");
                String newPhoneNumber = add.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter New Employee Salary :");
                double newSalary = add.nextDouble();

                if(selection == 1){
                    System.out.print("Enter New Employee Subject :");
                    String newSubject = add.nextLine();
                    add.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter New Employee School :");
                    String newSchool = add.nextLine();
                    aca[totalEmployee] = new academic(newID,newName,newIC,newPhoneNumber,newSalary,newSubject,newSchool);
                    System.out.print(aca[totalEmployee].toString());
                    }
                else{
                    System.out.print("Enter New Employee Position :");
                    String newPosition = add.nextLine();
                    add.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter New Employee Department :");
                    String newDepartment = add.nextLine();
                    admin[totalEmployee] = new academic(newID,newName,newIC,newPhoneNumber,newSalary,newPosition,newDepartment);
                    System.out.print(admin[totalEmployee].toString());
                    }

                System.out.print("\nDo you want to add more ? (Y/N)");
                choice = add.next().charAt(0);

        }while(choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y');
        MainMenu(aca, admin);
        }

        //Edit Employee
        public static void Edit(employee[] aca,employee[] admin){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the employee's ID");
            String id = input.nextLine();
            for(int i=0; i<totalEmployee; i++){
                if(aca[i].getId() == id){
                    String AcaID = aca[i].getId();
                    System.out.print("Enter employee's name: ");
                    String name = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter employee's IC number(eg.930302-14-5434): ");
                    String IC = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter employee's Phone Number: ");
                    String tel = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter the Salary: ");
                    double salary = input.nextDouble();
                    System.out.print("Enter the Subject: ");
                    String subject = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.print("Enter the School: ");
                    String school = input.nextLine();
                    admin[i] = new academic(id,name,IC, tel, salary, subject, school);
                    }
                    else if(admin[i].getId() == id){
                        String AdminID = admin[i].getId();
                        System.out.print("Enter employee's name: ");
                        String name = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter employee's IC number(eg.92030-10-55588): ");
                        String IC = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter employee's Phone Number: ");
                        String tel = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter the Salary: ");
                        double salary = input.nextDouble();
                        System.out.print("Enter employee's position: ");
                        String position = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter employee's department: ");
                        String department = input.nextLine();
                        admin[i] = new academic(id,name,IC, tel, salary, position, department);
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.print("\nThis ID does not exist. \n Please re-type.");
                        Edit(aca,admin);
                    }
            }
        }

        //Delete Employee
        public static void Delete(employee[] aca,employee[] admin){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the employee's ID");
            String delete = input.nextLine();
            //int deleteEMP = Integer.parseInt(input);
            for(int i=0; i<totalEmployee; i++){
                if(aca[i].getId() == delete){
                    aca[i].setShowEmployee(false);
                }
                else if(admin[i].getId() == delete){
                    admin[i].setShowEmployee(false);
                }
                else {
                System.out.print("\nWrong input. \n Please re-type.");
                Delete(aca,admin);
              }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: This is way too much code. Try to trim it down to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that shows your problem.

Answer (score 3):

`Employee` has two constructors: one that takes no arguments, the other takes 4 Strings, a double and a boolean.

In line 19 of `academic` you try to call `super` (which is `employee`) with 4 Strings and a double but no boolean. Since there is no such constructor in `employee` you get the error.

This code SHOULD NOT compile. The fact that it did suggests you are doing something odd in your compile process. Try compiling everything from scratch and see if you get the compile error.

Answer (score 1):

im surprised this compiles.

in the admin constructor you call

```
    super(id, name, ic, tel, salary);
```

but the employee doesnt have such a constructor. you are missing the needed last argument which is a boolean.

also: you should initialize count in employee class as 0 to avoid NullPointer

Answer (score 0):

> After I compile it shows that the compile was successful But as soon as I try to run it, it shows me this message:
>
> ```
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: employee.<init>(...
> ```

This means that you need to recompile the classes that depend on the `employee` classes constructor.  And when you do this, you will most likely find that you have your `academic` class doesn't compile.

If you are compiling by hand (i.e. no build tool) is a good idea to recompile *all* of your classes whenever you make a change.  Otherwise, you will miss problems that happen because (for example) you removed or changed the signature of a method constructor or field.

Rather than compiling by hand, it is better to use a build tool or an IDE.  I expect they will teach you about that soon ...

---

And while I have your attention, you class names violate a fundamental Java style rule.  All class names should start with an uppercase letter.  Change the class names, and rename the source files to match.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to delete all your class files and try to recompile your java sources.
2. Try to use clean process in your compiler next time you compile